# mongoose unique type — does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, database

why mongoose unique type does not work?
Every time i have duplicates in datebase.

```
   'use strict';
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

    var matchSchema = new Schema({
        url: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        league: String,
        league_url: String,
        team_left: String,
        team_left_url: String,
        team_right: String,
        team_right_url: String,
        start: String
    });

    let Match = mongoose.model('Match', matchSchema);

    let test = new Match({
        url: '/match/Q7u11iDN/',
        league: '123',
        league_url: '123',
        team_left: '123',
        team_left_url: '123',
        team_right: '123',
        team_right_url: '123',
        start: '09.08.2016 22:00'
    });

    test.save((err, test, affected) => {
        mongoose.connection.close();
    });

    Match.find({}, (err, test) => {
        console.log(test);
        console.log(test[0].league);
    });
```

Yes, i restart mongodb, and drop database, too.
P.S:
'Indexes are defined through ensureIndex every time a model is compiled for a certain connection / database. This means that indexes will only be ensured once during the lifetime of your app.'

How can i use this?